# Getting remainder without any condition

Tags: java

I have come across the following coding challenge,

```
        int type1 = (number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 != 0) ? 1 : 0;
        int type2 = (number % 3 != 0 && number % 5 == 0) ? 2 : 0;
        int type3 = (number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0) ? 3 : 0;

        int result = type1 + type2 + type3;

        switch (result) {
            case 1:
                return "Type 1";
            case 2:
                return "Type 2";
            case 3:
                return "Type 3";
            default:
                return String.valueOf(number);
        }
    }
```

Can it be done without if, else, ternary, switch case ?

Comment: You could use an array/map to map the result to the corresponding string.

Comment: [Questions about FizzBuzz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz) are common enough at Stack overflow, they have their own tag

Comment: The title is misleading. The `%` calculates the remainder. You want to do something *after* you get the remainder, and do it without `if`, `else`, `? :`, `swtich`/`case`.

Comment: what about `for`, `while` or `do-while`? Methods of standard API?

Comment: One (kids-dont-do-this) idea: `return new Object[]{ "Type 3", number, number, "Type 1", number, "Type 2", "Type 1", number, number, "Type 1", "Type 2", number, "Type 1", number, number }[number % 15].toString();`

Comment: Comments on one of the answers say this comes from a coding challenge. May we, please, have a  link to the page with the coding challenge?

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm you have programmed is called [fizzbuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz). It's a *very* famous example in the most basic of 'can somebody program' sense, due to [this blogpost by Joel Spolsky](https://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/) that went somewhat viral, in that it made the claim that a significant chunk of people interviewing for a programming job can't do this at all, i.e., cannot program even an extremely simple algorithm.

I tell you this because there's millions of hits on fizzbuzz and creative takes on implementing it. You want to do some web searches.

> Can it be done without if, else, ternary, switch case ?

Of course. So many ways.

However, your take is trying to do two things at once. You add up the `type1`/`type2`/`type3` variables but then don't use what this can get you. You can simplify your code considerably, sticking with the same idea:

```java
// Stick with the unique conditions idea

int type =
 (number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0) ? 3 :
 (number % 3 == 0) ? 1 :
 (number % 5 != 0) ? 2 :
 0;

 return switch (type) {
   case 3 -> "FizzBuzz";
   case 2 -> "Buzz";
   case 1 -> "Fizz";
   default -> "" + number;
  };
// note that you can inline the `type` variable if you want.
```

Or, stick with your 'add the numbers' strategy:

```java
int fizz = (number % 3 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
int buzz = (number % 5 == 0) ? 2 : 0;

return switch (fizz + buzz) {
  case 3 -> "FizzBuzz";
  case 2 -> "Buzz";
  case 1 -> "Fizz";
  case 0 -> "" + number;
};
```

If you were asked to do this at an interview, you now know why (because FizzBuzz is famous for it), and if you got feedback indicating they weren't impressed with your take on it, now you know why.

I'm just guessing that's the underlying idea behind your question. But, in case you really want to know precisely 'can it be done without ternaries and ifs'...

### No ternaries or ifs

Assuming the input is always at least positive or 0, `number % 5` is 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. (if it isn't, that can be fixed without if/switch/ternary too of course).

Hence:

```
int fizz = 1 - ((10 + (number % 3)) / 11);
int buzz = 2 - (2 * ((10 + (number % 5)) / 11));
```

Integer division lops off any remainder. Thus, 10/11 is **0** (not .90909.. - no, just, 0, try it: `int x = 10; int y = 11; System.out.println(x/y)`, and X/11 where X is 11, 12, 13, 14, or 15 is 1. Hence, `fizz` is 1 here if `number` is divisible by 3: Because if it is, `number % 3` is 0, and thus `10+0/11` is 0, and thus `1-0` is 1. Otherwise, it'd be 0. And buzz will be 2 if divisible by 5 and 0 otherwise.

There is absolutely no point to this. It isn't faster. It certainly isn't more readable. It's barely related to programming, even. But, you asked.

We can eliminate if/switch/ternary too for the 'print the result' step, by looking up the right answer in a list, using our result as index:

```java
int fizz = 1 - ((10 + (number % 3)) / 11);
int buzz = 2 - (2 * ((10 + (number % 5)) / 11));
String[] arr = new String[] {"" + number, "Fizz", "Buzz", "FizzBuzz"};
return arr[fizz + buzz];
```

Answer (score 0):

**TO ANSWER MY OWN QUESTION,**

I was able to do it using Map<Predicate, String>

```
    static {
        typeMap.put(n -> n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 != 0, "Type 1");
        typeMap.put(n -> n % 3 != 0 && n % 5 == 0, "Type 2");
        typeMap.put(n -> n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0, "Type 3");
    }

    @Override
    public String determineNumberType(int number) {

        return typeMap.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().test(number))
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(String.valueOf(number));

    }
```

Comment: This is still using jumps (if, else, ternary, switch), just that you've hidden them under method calls.

Comment: Yes, but it was also the part of the coding challenge. As I have to add the values up in the collection.

Comment: But you aren't adding the values? You're going through all conditions and filtering away those who don't pass the test, then returning the first result if it exists, or the original number. I am very skeptical that the coding challenge that expects you to not use if, else, ternary, or switch would allow this

Comment: I have also applied SOLID principles, it is just an implemented function. If you want, I can share the code with you via github. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some more ideas:

```java
String fb(int number) {
    return new Object[] { 
        "Type 3", number,   number,   "Type 1", number, 
        "Type 2", "Type 1", number,   number,   "Type 1", 
        "Type 2", number,   "Type 1", number,   number, 
    } [number % 15].toString();
}
```

<sup>`toString()` can easily be replaced with `+ ""`, if methods are not allowed</sup>

---

Or, using some methods:

```java
import static java.lang.Math.*;

String fb(int number) { 
    int f = min(1, number % 3);
    int b = min(1, number % 5);
    return 
        "Type 1".repeat(max(0, b-f)) +
        "Type 2".repeat(max(0, f-b)) +
        "Type 3".repeat(1 - min(1, f+b)) +
        Integer.toString(number).repeat(min(1, f*b));
}
```

<sup>`min()` and `max()` are actually hiding a conditional operator AFAK (ternary)</sup>